# Trim unwanted characters in a Java String

Tags: java, string, split, trim, text-processing

I have few Java Strings like below:

```
ab-android-regression-4.4-git
ab-ios-regression-4.4-git
ab-tablet-regression-4.4-git
```

However, I do not want such lengthy and unwanted names and so I want to get rid of starting `ab-` and ending `-git` part. The pattern for all the Strings is the same (starts with ab and ends with git)

Is there a function/class in Java that will help me in trimming such things? For example, something like:

```
String test = "ab-android-regression-4.4-git";
test.trim(ab, git)
```

Also, can `StringUtils` class help me with this? Thoughts on regular expressions?

***EDITED PART:*** I also want to know how to eliminate the `-` characters in the Strings and change everything to uppercase letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that's more general purpose to remove a prefix and suffix from a string:

```
public static String trim (String str, String prefix, String suffix)
{
    int indexOfLast = str.lastIndexOf(suffix);

    // Note: you will want to do some error checking here 
    // in case the suffix does not occur in the passed in String

    str = str.substring(0, indexOfLast);

    return str.replaceFirst(prefix, "");
}
```

Usage:

```
String test = "ab-android-regression-4.4-git";
String trim = trim(test, "ab-", "-git"));
```

To remove the "-" and make uppercase, then just do:

```
trim = trim.replaceAll("-", " ").toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `test = test.replace("ab-", "")` and similar for the `"-git"` or you can use `test = StringUtils.removeStart(test, "ab-")` and similarly, `removeEnd`.

I prefer the latter if you can use `StringUtils` because it won't ever accidentally remove the middle of the filename if those expressions are matched.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question to eliminate more data and change to uppercase letters.

Comment: If you want spaces instead of hyphens, use `test.replaceAll("-"," ")`. If you want no spaces use `test.replaceAll("-","")`. If you want all uppercase letters, use `test.toUpperCase()`. If you want real capital casing on each word, you'll need to do some of your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since the parts to trim are constant in size, you should simply use substring :

```
yourString.substring(3, yourString.length - 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question to eliminate more data and change to uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

If your string always contains ab- at the begining and -git at the end then here is the code

```
String test = "ab-android-regression-4.4-git";
test=test.substring(3, s.length() - 4);
System.out.println("s is"+s);  //output is android-regression-4.4
```

To know more about substrings click https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html